Caught IndexError in DataLoader worker process 0 with custom dataloader
I am implementing contrastive learning for a simple classification task on tabular data:
class Contrastive(pl.LightningModule):
    
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, lr, temperature, weight_decay, max_epochs=50):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters()
        assert self.hparams.temperature > 0.0 #positive temperature
        #Encoder
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_dim, 2*hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(2*hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
            )
        
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = optim.AdamW(self.parameters(),
                               lr=self.hparams.lr,
                               weight_decay=self.hparams.weight_decay)
        lr_scheduler=optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer,
                                                        T_max=self.hparams.max_epochs,
                                                        eta_min=self.hparams.lr/50)
        return [optimizer], [lr_scheduler]
    
    def info_nce_loss(self, batch, mode='train'):
        tabs, labels = batch
        tabs = tabs.to(torch.float32)
        
        feats = self.encoder(tabs)
        cos_sim = F.cosine_similarity(feats[:, None], feats[None, :], dim=-1)
        self_mask = torch.eye(cos_sim.shape[0], dtype=torch.bool, device=cos_sim.device)
        cos_sim.masked_fill_(self_mask, -9e15)
        pos_mask = torch.zeros(cos_sim.shape, dtype=torch.bool)
        for i in range(label.size[0]):
            pos_mask[i, :] = labels==labels[i]
        cos_sim = cos_sim/self.hparams.temperature
        nll = -cos_sim[pos_mask] + torch.logsumexp(cos_sim, dim-1)
        nll = nll.mean()
        self.log(mode+'_loss', nll)
        comb_sim = torch.cat([cos_sim[pos_mask][:, None],
                              cos_sim.masked_fill(pos_mask, -9e15)], dim=-1)
        sim_argsort = comb_sim.argsort(dim=-1, descending=True).argmin(dim=-1)
        self.log(mode+'_acc_top1', (sim_argsort==0).flot().mean())
        self.log(mode+'acc_top5', (sim_argsort < 5).float().mean())
        self.log(mode+'acc_mean_pos', 1+sim_argsort.float().mean())
        
        return nll
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        return self.info_nce_loss(batch, mode='train')
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        self.info_nce_loss(batch, mode='val')

class DrillingDataset(Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, msr, label, transform=None):
        self.msr = msr
        self.label = label
        self.transform = transform
        
    def __len__(self):
        return label.shape[0]
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()
        
        sample = self.msr[idx, :]
        
        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)
            
        return sample, label[idx]

def train_contrastive(data_train, label_train, data_val, label_val, batch_size, max_epochs=500, **kwargs):
    trainer = pl.Trainer(default_root_dir=os.path.join(CHECKPOINT_PATH, 'Contrastive'),
                        accelerator="gpu" if str(device).startswith("cuda") else "cpu",
                        devices=1, max_epochs=max_epochs,
                        callbacks=[ModelCheckpoint(save_weights_only=True, mode='max', monitor='val_acc_top5'),
                                  LearningRateMonitor('epoch')])
    trainer.logger._default_hp_metric = None
    
    set_train = DrillingDataset(msr=data_train, label=label_train, 
                                   transform=transforms.Compose([Noise(0.1), Missing(0.05)]))
    set_val = DrillingDataset(msr=data_val, label=label_val)
    train_loader = DataLoader(set_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True,
                                       drop_last=True, pin_memory=True, num_workers=NUM_WORKERS)
    val_loader = DataLoader(set_val, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True,
                                drop_last=True,pin_memory=True, num_workers=NUM_WORKERS)
    
    pl.seed_everything(42)
    model = Contrastive(max_epochs=max_epochs, **kwargs)
    trainer.fit(model, train_loader, val_loader)
    model = Contrastive.load_from_checkpoint(trainer.checkpoint_callback.best_model_path)
    
    return model

And get this error:
IndexError: Caught IndexError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 308, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)  # type: ignore[possibly-undefined]
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_24260/2717784420.py", line 15, in __getitem__
    sample = self.msr[idx, :]
IndexError: index 96 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 72

I have tried reducing the batch size (even with batch size = 1 the issue remains) and the number of workers as I read this might be a memory issue but it didn't work either

In your DrillingDataset class, change label in your __len__ and __getitem__ methods to self.label. At the moment the class will be using a globally defined label variable, rather than the variable that you are initialising the class with.
